# Need help with markdown formatting

Tags: support, markdown

Sometimes I need to style my lists like so:

- Item #1

  - Sub-Item #1
  - Sub-Item #2
- Item #2

  - Sub-item #3

For some reason it's impossible to add an extra line between Sub-item #2 and Item #2.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294355/php-yaml-parsers/3691710#3691710) to see what I am talking about (after "syck," I used a dot to create a space)

Is there a better way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `<br/>` elements.

```
 * Item #1
   * Sub-Item #1
   * Sub-Item #2
<br/><br/>
 * Item #2
   * Sub-Item #3
```

produces:

- Item #1

  - Sub-Item #1
  - Sub-Item #2
- Item #2

  - Sub-Item #3

Comment: Should be `<br/>`

Comment: @Hans - strictly speaking it should, but most (if not all) browsers cope with `<br>`

Comment: @Hans: Stackoverflow does not use XHTML. If you view source, you should see a lot of `<br>`.

Comment: I changed it, but <br/> isn't *necessary*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `&nbsp;` instead of a dot, which makes the hack less visible.

> - Item #1
>
>   - Sub-item #1
>   - Sub-item #2
> - Item #2
>
>   - Sub-item #3

Comment: That was my first attempt but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @rchern: Works on Firefox. The source code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/fce535d2-94ee-43f9-9c4a-601474f6ac71/view-source